# How can I improve the directional flow of my furnace exhaust pipe?

Tags: heating, furnace, exhaust-vent

This one's for the creative folks. I'm in a condo on the top floor and I have a side neighbor. Both our furnaces exhaust out the back, under a four-foot roof section overhang (sticks out about a foot with a gutter). They're really close to each other (2-3 ft away) and our bedroom windows (3 ft down and maybe 3 ft. to the side, mine is on the left side of the photo). Here's my issue: The wind almost constantly blows from west to east there, creating a wind tunnel and always blowing the exhaust past my windows – I’d say 90% of the time they are gusting past my condo.

Is there a way to create a wind break, possibly by placing some barrier, plexi or something, vertically under that eave and down between the exhausts to lessen the down draft of these furnaces? Thanks in advance.

[image: back of wall with pipes, mine on left]

---

I am open to other ideas too, besides a windbreak. Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem? Your furnace cuts out?

Comment: @Mazura -- no, his problem is that the furnace exhaust blows into his window!

Comment: Why's the furnace running if the window's open? Or... why's the window open if the furnace is running?

Answer (score 1):

Extending the exhausts (to the roof or around the corner) seems the only reasonable solution to me.

Check the installer's manual to see if it needs to be in 3" for the new distance length.